# Laravel Auth::user() pluck strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel

```
$items = Auth::user()->pluck( 'id');
```

results

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object(
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 7
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 9
        ...
    )
[escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => )
```

with all user ids, Instead of the expected single element in the 'items' array.
Can anyone explain what this is about?

Edit:
for more clarity

```
$physicalExercises = Auth::user()
    ->with('physicalExercises')
    ->first()
    ->physicalExercises
    ->pluck('name', 'id');
```

and

```
$physicalExercises = User::where('id', Auth::id())
    ->with('physicalExercises')
    ->first()
     ->physicalExercises
     ->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Has a different result.

Comment: Use do `Auth::user()->id`, you don't need to pluck it

Comment: you are creating a new query that is plucking all the records ... there is no `pluck` on a single model object as there is nothing to 'pluck' as its not a collection

Comment: Also you can use `Auth::id()`

Answer (score 1):

Both function on question have different behavior.

```
// Retrieve the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();
 
// Retrieve the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Check the [authenticated docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) for more info.

PS: You can do like `Auth::user()->id` but simply do `Auth::id()`, it's more cleaner to access the id.